# “Lose (the) [noun]” as in “get rid of [noun]”

Tags: idiomatic-language

Apart from the common expression “to lose weight”, I am unsure about when it is idiomatic to use the word “lose” to mean “get rid of”. I’ve prepared a few example sentences, and would be grateful to know if they all sound natural to a native speaker:

1: “After a few minutes of sprinting, Bob managed to lose the dog that had been chasing him.”
In this sentence “lose” would be another way of saying “escape” or “outrun”.

2: “The bouncer told Allie that she would have to “lose the geek” in order to enter the nightclub, but she would never abandon her friend.” In this sentence “lose” would be a (rude/hip?) way of saying “part ways with”.

3: “Harry was frequently told that he should “lose the beard” or “lose the axe”, but he enjoyed looking like a lumberjack.” In this sentence “lose” would mean “shave” and “stop carrying around” respectively.

Comment: Yes, those all sound natural.

Comment: @Katy care to write an answer please.  Leaving questions answered in comments deters other from writing answers and results in "unanswered" questions festering in the system.

Comment: Note that 2 and 3 are typically American English. They aren't naturally used by British English speakers, although British English speakers commonly borrow US slang so it would not be completely unheard of for us to use 'lose' like this in imitation of AmEng, and we would certainly understand it.